# How do I sort into chronological order of two GUID fields from same table?

Tags: mysql, sorting, uuid, hierarchical-data, bubble-sort

### Question

I have a table with two GUID fields, one of which indicates which GUID is superior (`SuperiorGUID`) to that row (`ObjectGUID`). This table exists in a MySQL 5.7 database. I need to order the rows in this table by the daisy chain of these two fields.

How do I order ObjectGUID in sequence where the latest version is `SuperiorGUID` = '`ffffffff-ffff-ffff-ffff-ffffffffffff`'?

### Table VersionTracking vt

| ObjectGUID | SuperiorGUID |
| --- | --- |
| 15c9cc74-7653-4000-a3a7-8ab7efe5f5f4 | 6797d1f2-b81c-4db9-8a8b-ce3e9afc96f7 |
| 2bb02d4b-a444-11eb-8b72-000c29e16cdc | d72fe08a-2034-4615-96b9-a4e3e2d496a1 |
| 6797d1f2-b81c-4db9-8a8b-ce3e9afc96f7 | ab921294-6d3a-4cb3-8adb-3f0f76fa8635 |
| a637d8be-8840-4053-9082-9e86b141ddca | ffffffff-ffff-ffff-ffff-ffffffffffff |
| ab921294-6d3a-4cb3-8adb-3f0f76fa8635 | a637d8be-8840-4053-9082-9e86b141ddca |
| d72fe08a-2034-4615-96b9-a4e3e2d496a1 | 15c9cc74-7653-4000-a3a7-8ab7efe5f5f4 |

### Desired Output

| ObjectGUID | SuperiorGUID |
| --- | --- |
| a637d8be-8840-4053-9082-9e86b141ddca | ffffffff-ffff-ffff-ffff-ffffffffffff |
| ab921294-6d3a-4cb3-8adb-3f0f76fa8635 | a637d8be-8840-4053-9082-9e86b141ddca |
| 6797d1f2-b81c-4db9-8a8b-ce3e9afc96f7 | ab921294-6d3a-4cb3-8adb-3f0f76fa8635 |
| 15c9cc74-7653-4000-a3a7-8ab7efe5f5f4 | 6797d1f2-b81c-4db9-8a8b-ce3e9afc96f7 |
| d72fe08a-2034-4615-96b9-a4e3e2d496a1 | 15c9cc74-7653-4000-a3a7-8ab7efe5f5f4 |
| 2bb02d4b-a444-11eb-8b72-000c29e16cdc | d72fe08a-2034-4615-96b9-a4e3e2d496a1 |

Comment: you will need mysql 8 or mariadb to do this, unless your maximum chain length is ~30 or less

Comment: in your examples, SuperiorGUID is always unique, but is that always the case?

Comment: Yes, `SuperiorGUID` is always unique. If it is absolutely necessary, it is OK to impose a maximum chain length. I have an idea of how I could do it but it would be a long query with as subquery nestings as deep as the number of maximum chainlinks I'm willing to tolerate (or is of still reasonable execution time).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Demonstrating with a maximum chain length of three, I would do:

```
select
    elt(d, vt1.ObjectGUID, vt2.ObjectGUID, vt3.ObjectGUID) ObjectGUID,
    elt(d, vt1.SuperiorGUID, vt2.SuperiorGUID, vt3.SuperiorGUID) SuperiorGUID
from (
    select 1 d union all select 2 union all select 3
) depths
cross join vt vt1
left join vt vt2 on d>=2 and vt2.SuperiorGUID=vt1.ObjectGUID
left join vt vt3 on d>=3 and vt3.SuperiorGUID=vt2.ObjectGUID
where vt1.SuperiorGUID='ffffffff-ffff-ffff-ffff-ffffffffffff'
order by d
```

This seems more straightforward to me than a subquery-based solution, but is restricted by the limit of 61 joined tables.

Answer (score 0):

The recursive query solution, available in MySQL 8.0:

```
WITH RECURSIVE cte AS (
  SELECT ObjectGUID, SuperiorGuid, 1 AS level
  FROM MyTable
  WHERE SuperiorGuid = 'ffffffff-ffff-ffff-ffff-ffffffffffff'
  UNION ALL
  SELECT m.ObjectGuid, m.SuperiorGuid, cte.level+1
  FROM MyTable AS m JOIN cte ON m.SuperiorGuid = cte.ObjectGUID 
)
SELECT ObjectGUID, SuperiorGUID FROM cte ORDER BY level;
```